# Bluetooth Headset sound stops and restarts automatically

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, asus

Recently i bought AUS TUF FA566IU-HN246T and installed ubuntu 20.04. Whenever i connect my bluetooth headphones with laptop and play music, sound starts, however after a few seconds it stops, and then after 4-5 seconds it again starts, starting from the position the sound ended.

To give an analogy, it sort of feels like a buffer not being flushed to bluetooth and then all being sent all at once. Any tips/pointers where should i look to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading to kernel version 5.7.16-050716-generic

```
cd /tmp
mkdir kernal
cd kernal
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.16/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.16-050716-generic_5.7.16-050716.202008190732_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.16/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.7.16-050716-generic_5.7.16-050716.202008190732_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.16/amd64/linux-modules-5.7.16-050716-generic_5.7.16-050716.202008190732_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
```